# Execute command only with a certain permission

Tags: c#, permissions, bots, discord.net

I'm working on a Discord-bot and I want a command to be only executable if the user using the command has a certain "Discord permission".

This is the code I use:

```
commands.CreateCommand("test")
            .MinPermissions((int)Permissions.User)
            .Do(async e =>
            {
                /* execute something here... */
            });
```

`User` is defined in the class `Permissions`.

Thing is, everytime I try to start the application, it gives me this:

> This operation requires PermissionLevelService to be added to DiscordClient.

What am I doing wrong? Where do I add this `PermissionLevelService`?

EDIT: Got it to work after upgrading from Discord.NET 0.9.6. to 1.0.1., just with a different syntax.

Comment: Which version of discord.net are you using

Comment: I'm using the old 0.9.6.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to 1.0.x instead, considering 0.9.6 is deprecated

Comment: Yes, I've heard about that. Since the bot was written quite a while ago, some things won't work if I upgrade it to 1.0.

Comment: Everything that works in 0.9 should also work in 1.0, but under different syntaxes. However, if you run into issues there, you most likely could ask a new question with that as well.

Comment: Alright, I will try it out. Do you know if that's why the Permission-thing isn't working?

Comment: No, (otherwise I would have answered). I haven't touched 0.9.6 since the RC of 1.0, as there are a lot of things not fully implemented/bugged in 0.9.6 that do work in 1.0 properly. This might be one of them.

Comment: Alright, thank you.